# jQuery resizable table IE issue

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

First off, I'm NOT trying to re-size columns of a table. I'm trying to re-size the table itself.

What I've found with jQuery is the placement of html is incorrect. Seen in the debugger of IE or whatever browsers debugger.

Using this code.

jQuery:

```
$("table").resizable();
```

Html:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

The html code rendered is (seen in the debugger):

```
<table class="ui-resizable">
    <thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
</table>
```

As you can see, div nodes are places directly within the table node which is not correct html. Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx1egssj/21/)

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: is it working in google chrome and Firefox?

Comment: I've only tested in Chrome and IE and yes Chrome works fine. My main concern is IE.

Comment: Funny though. The jsfiddle example isn't working in either browser. But I have fully functional code that is working in Chrome.

Comment: Looks like a mismatch of jquery and jquery ui versions since the console is full of errors.

Comment: @epascarello can you please explain?

Comment: The jquery ui version is using browser.msie, that has been dropped from the latest jQuery core.

Comment: I see what you are talking about. I fixed with the right references. Still tho, it does not work correctly in IE. 

http://jsfiddle.net/yx1egssj/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the problem with the script file that you used in your application

Add the following resources

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yx1egssj/18/

Comment: That comes close. But, I'm using the latest jQuery "edge". Also, the latest jQuery UI. I can not change the version either since other objects rely on the latest. I did forget to add the UI css reference. Here is an update.

http://jsfiddle.net/yx1egssj/20/

Still it doesn't change the fact that it is not correct HTML. IE is strict on HTML code.

Comment: After looking at your solution a little further. I do like the fact that you can re-size something within an element as well. So, I modified it to work for how I wanted with your help of course. http://jsfiddle.net/yx1egssj/24/